# Can structure always end with a semicolon in C

Tags: c, structure

Here I have two structures. First is:

```
struct complex {
    double real, imaginary;
};
```

which I know that it must be end with a semicolon.

But this one with a function

```
struct complex add_complex(struct complex c1, struct complex c2) {
    struct complex c3;
    c3.real = c1.real + c2.real;
    c3.imaginary = c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary;
    return c3;
}
```

Here if I don't include a semicolon at the end, then the compiler will generate no error. 
Why?

Comment: A function doesn't end with a semicolon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A structure definition must always have a semicolon at the end. Thus you'd get a compiler error if you removed the `;` from the `struct complex` definition.

The second one (`add_complex`)isn't a structure definition, it's a function returning a structure. Functions don't have semicolons at the end of them.

> - I mean, if I write like this struct complex add_complex() { }; then this one also true. Why?

It being "OK", actually depends on the compiler. Most compilers I've used (gcc and Micosoft's for example) do allow this, but can be made to display a warning/error with the correct flags (adding `-pedantic` to gcc will give: `warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-pedantic]` and you can add `-Werror`) to turn that into an error.)

Comment: But If I include semicolon in this structed function, then also no error generated

Comment: @ashish2expert - There is no such thing as a "structed function". You have a function, it returns *something*. That something doesn't matter it is stil written as a function. In this particular case it just so happens to be a structure that you're returning.

Comment: I mean, if I write like this struct complex add_complex() { }; then this one also true. Why

Comment: @ashish2expert: that's a stray semicolon, which is allowed but meaningless in C.

Comment: It might consider the semicolon as an empty statement after the function 

`Fn1()`
`{`
    
    `}`
    
    `;`

Comment: 6.8.3 does not apply to semicolons outside of function definitions. There are no syntactic statements outside of function definitions, just external declarations (after preprocessing). Stray semicolons outside of functions are not part of standard C, although some compilers might ignore them.

Comment: @Eric - Thanks for that, I've updated accordingly. I wasn't sure if that section also applied outside function blocks or not but I figured I'd be corrected if that wasn't the case. Are you aware of any compilers that *do not* ignore them?

Comment: @Mike: Apple clang 4.0 and Apple gcc 4.2.1 display a warning when `-pedantic` is used.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a structure definition for immediately declaring a variable or other things.
For example, you can do

```
struct complex {
    double real, imaginary;
} number;
```

for declaring the variable `number` with type `struct complex`.
You can also declare your function like this

```
struct complex {
    double real, imaginary;
} add_complex(struct complex c1, struct complex c2) {
    struct complex c3;
    c3.real = c1.real + c2.real;
    c3.imaginary = c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary;
    return c3;
}
```

You don't need to put a semicolon after the function definition because this definition can't be used for anything else.

Comment: The statement that you can use a structure definition for declaring other things does not explain why a structure definition ends with a semicolon and a function definition does not. I suppose you could argue that, if a structure definition did not end with a semicolon, the compiler would not know whether the following identifier was part of the statement (an identifier being declared) or something else (what?). However, that explanation is not present in this answer. Additionally, it would have to explain why this is not a problem with a function definition.